# Undefined index: usertypename in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-2.1

Controller part code

```
$Viewcustomer=$this->Viewcustomer->query("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(usertype_name SEPARATOR ',') as usertypename, customer_name FROM `pre`.`customer` AS `Viewcustomer` WHERE `Viewcustomer`.`customer_status` = 0 AND `Viewcustomer`.`customer_type` = 'B1'  
GROUP BY `customer_id`  DESC"); 
$this->set("Viewcustomer",$Viewcustomer);
```

view part code

```
 foreach($Viewcustomer as $customers){
  echo  $customers['Viewcustomer']['usertypename'];
    }
```

Comment: I'm curious how you can use three CakePHP versions at the same time. Tell me? Or fix your tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`usertypename` should not come in `$customers['Viewcustomer']['usertypename'];`

this should be 
 `$customers['0']['usertypename'];` 
please print your array and share your code